# No css/javascript after httpauth on android

Tags: android, jquery-mobile, android-webview, http-authentication

I added a HashMap for every URL I'm loading on my WebView (Android 4.x):

```
map = new HashMap<String, String>();
        String usernamePassword = "user:password";
        String authorization = "Basic " + Base64.encodeToString(usernamePassword.getBytes("UTF-8"), Base64.NO_WRAP);
        map.put("Authorization", authorization);
        mainWebView.loadUrl("http://my.url/", map);
```

Now I'm trying to open a url containing javscript and css (jquery mobile). Just fyi I also override URL loading using the map:

```
@Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        view.loadUrl(url, map);
        return true;
    }
```

The content of the page is shown as expected but html only. So there is no stylesheet and javscript isn't working either. I expect it can't load the ressources due to missing authentication when requesting the stylesheet/javascript file.

Any ideas how to tell the android webview to forward the authentication?

Comment: No idea why the CSS/JS _requires_ authentication.

Comment: i would think shouldOverrideUrlLoading should return false, but not sure

Comment: also, you should look into onReceivedHttpAuthRequest rather than try to intercept url loadings

Comment: or, setHttpAuthUsernamePassword (in webview)